# Azure - Update service principal scope

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I've created a App and added a resource group. How can I update service principal and add a second resource group?  Also is it possible to make it subscription wide access instead of just resource group based?

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name "MyApp" --role contributor --scopes /subscriptions/{SubID}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroup1}
```

I can't find any article describing how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an additional resource group you can do this:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp" --role Contributor --scopes /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup1} /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup2}
```

**Scope** is the set of resources that the access applies to. In Azure, you can specify a scope at four levels: **management group**, **subscription**, **resource group**, and **resource**. Scopes are structured in a parent-child relationship. Each level of hierarchy makes the scope more specific. You can assign roles at any of these levels of scope. The level you select determines how widely the role is applied. Lower levels inherit role permissions from higher levels.

### Scope for a role assignment

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-steps#step-3-identify-the-needed-scope

Comment: Thanks. To make it subscription wide, I just used the following `az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp" --role Contributor --scopes /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}`